# Issues linting protos with Buf

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I'm trying to set a repo for my proto files.

I have the following structure:

```
buf.gen.yaml
folderA
    buf.yaml
    v1
        file1.proto
folderB
    buf.yaml
    v1
        file2.proto
```

file1.proto needs to import a message from file2.proto, I can generate the protos code without any issues with the following:

```
buf generate
```

File A imports file B with the following

```
import "folderB/v1/file2.proto";
```

I tried adding a buf.work.yaml with the following:

```
version: v1
directories:
  - folderA
  - folderB
```

but I still get `folderA/v1/file1.proto:7:8:folderB/v1/file2.proto: does not exist` when I try to lint, but can still generate the code.

Can someone explain to me what am I missing?

Thanks.